# Syntax error in "psql" , command not get executed

Tags: postgresql, csv, syntax-error, psql, timescaledb

I am using timescaledb.

The doumentation I am following is [Using PostgreSQL's COPY](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/getting-started/migrating-data#csv-import) to migrate data from a csv  file to timescale db. The name of csv file is *test.csv*.

I created the db named *test* , the name of table is *test1*. Table is a hypertable as per the timescaledb documentation.

The table's structure and csv files structure are the same.

While executing the following command in cmd I am not getting a result other than an addition of `-` symbol in the console command `test-#`

```
psql -d test -c "\COPY test1 FROM C:\Users\DEGEJOS\Downloads\test.csv CSV"
```

[image: NO Response in Console]

If I put `;` after the command
`psql -d test -c "\COPY test1 FROM C:\Users\DEGEJOS\Downloads\test.csv CSV";`  I am getting a syntax error at Line 1.

[image: Syntax Error]

How can I solve this error and insert data from csv file to db.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run `psql` with `\COPY` inside `psql` session, thus you get an error in the second call, since `psql` keyword does not exist in SQL. [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html) is an executable.

To follow the instructions from Timescale, you need to call the command directly in CMD. I.e, call:

```
psql -d test -c "\COPY test1 FROM C:\Users\DEGEJOS\Downloads\test.csv CSV"
```

If you are in `C:\Users\DEGEJOS` as in your screenshoot, it will look like:

```
C:\Users\DEGEJOS\psql -d test -c "\COPY test1 FROM C:\Users\DEGEJOS\Downloads\test.csv CSV"
```

Comment: I tried to run the command directly in CMD. After exiting from postgresql / db as mentioned by you. 
The CMD is throwing a message "'C:\Users\DEGEJOS\psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: You need to write:
`psql -d test -c "\COPY test1 FROM C:\Users\DEGEJOS\Downloads\test.csv CSV"` in CMD, while you are in `C:\Users\DEGEJOS\ `. I.e., in the same way as you do in screenshot, but with different arguments to `psql`.